# java hibernate error "could not execute statement" in Session.save()

Tags: java, hibernate

```
/**
 * Description of bankbranchcontactdetailsBean
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain
 */
package com.beans;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity(name = "bankbranchcontactdetails")
@Table(name = "bankbranchcontactdetails", schema = "stserptest", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "BankBranchContactId") })
@TableGenerator(name = "bankbranchcontactdetailsgen", table = "bankbranchcontactdetails", pkColumnName = "BankBranchContactId")
public class bankbranchcontactdetailsBean extends SuperBeanClass implements
        SuperBeanInterface {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "mysql->int(10) unsigned", name = "BankBranchContactId", precision = 10, scale = 0, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer _BankBranchContactId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "mysql->int(10) unsigned", name = "BankBranchId", precision = 10, scale = 0, nullable = false)
    private Integer _BankBranchId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "mysql->enum('Phone','Mobile','Fax','Telex')", name = "ContactType", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private String _ContactType;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "mysql->varchar(20)", name = "Contact", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String _Contact;

    public bankbranchcontactdetailsBean() {

        _BankBranchId = 0;
        _ContactType = "";
        _Contact = "";
    }

    public bankbranchcontactdetailsBean(Integer __BankBranchId,
            String __ContactType, String __Contact) {

        _BankBranchId = __BankBranchId;
        _ContactType = __ContactType;
        _Contact = __Contact;
    }

    public Integer getBankBranchId() {
        return _BankBranchId;
    }

    public String getContactType() {
        return _ContactType;
    }

    public String getContact() {
        return _Contact;
    }

    public void setBankBranchId(Integer NewValue) {
        _BankBranchId = NewValue;
    }

    public void setContactType(String NewValue) {
        _ContactType = NewValue;
    }

    public void setContact(String NewValue) {
        _Contact = NewValue;
    }

}

/**
  * Description of hibernate.cfg.xml
  */
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">v32</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.stserp.beans.bankbranchcontactdetailsBean" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>


/**
 * Description of ManagerClass
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain
 */
package com.beans;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class ManagerClass {

    private static SessionFactory factory = null;
    private static ManagerClass _ManagerClass = null;

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                .buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return factory;
    }

    public static ManagerClass getInstance() throws ExceptionInInitializerError {
        try {
            if (factory == null) {
                factory = createSessionFactory();
            }
            if (_ManagerClass == null) {
                _ManagerClass = new ManagerClass();
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                    null,
                    "Failed to create sessionFactory object...\n"
                            + ex.getMessage(), "Error...", 0);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        } finally {
            return _ManagerClass;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> SaveBeansList(Session session, String entityName,
            ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass> BeansList)
            throws HibernateException {
        ArrayList<Integer> IDs = null;
        try {
            IDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (SuperBeanClass element : BeansList) {
                IDs.add((Integer) session.save(entityName, element));
            }
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return IDs;
    }

    public ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass> LoadTable(Session session,
            String TableName) throws HibernateException {
        ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass> beansList = null;
        try {
            beansList = (ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass>) session
                    .createQuery("FROM " + TableName).list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return beansList;
    }

    public ArrayList<?> LoadConditional(Session session, String _query)
            throws HibernateException {
        ArrayList<?> beansList = null;
        try {
            beansList = (ArrayList<? extends SuperBeanClass>) session
                    .createQuery(_query).list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return beansList;
    }

    public SuperBeanInterface LoadById(Session session, Class className,
            Integer ID) throws HibernateException {
        SuperBeanInterface BeanInterface = null;
        try {
            BeanInterface = (SuperBeanInterface) session.get(className, ID);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return BeanInterface;
    }

    public void DeleteById(Session session, Class className, Integer ID)
            throws HibernateException {
        try {
            session.delete(session.get(className, ID));
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Description of SuperBeanClass
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain
 */
package com.beans;

public class SuperBeanClass {
    public SuperBeanClass() {
    }
}


/**
 * Description of SuperBeanInterface
 *
 * @author Vishal Jain
 */
package com.beans;

public interface SuperBeanInterface {
}


OUTPUT

    enter code here

ClassName -- FileName -- MethodName -- LineNo.
org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate -- SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java -- convert -- 82
org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter -- StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java -- convert -- 49
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -- SqlExceptionHelper.java -- convert -- 125
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper -- SqlExceptionHelper.java -- convert -- 110
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl -- ResultSetReturnImpl.java -- executeUpdate -- 136
org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate -- IdentityGenerator.java -- executeAndExtract -- 96
org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate -- AbstractReturningDelegate.java -- performInsert -- 58
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -- AbstractEntityPersister.java -- insert -- 2975
org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister -- AbstractEntityPersister.java -- insert -- 3487
org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction -- EntityIdentityInsertAction.java -- execute -- 81
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue -- ActionQueue.java -- execute -- 377
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue -- ActionQueue.java -- addResolvedEntityInsertAction -- 214
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue -- ActionQueue.java -- addInsertAction -- 194
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue -- ActionQueue.java -- addAction -- 178
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener -- AbstractSaveEventListener.java -- addInsertAction -- 321
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener -- AbstractSaveEventListener.java -- performSaveOrReplicate -- 286
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener -- AbstractSaveEventListener.java -- performSave -- 192
org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener -- AbstractSaveEventListener.java -- saveWithGeneratedId -- 125
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener -- DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java -- saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId -- 206
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener -- DefaultSaveEventListener.java -- saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId -- 55
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener -- DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java -- entityIsTransient -- 191
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener -- DefaultSaveEventListener.java -- performSaveOrUpdate -- 49
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener -- DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java -- onSaveOrUpdate -- 90
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl -- SessionImpl.java -- fireSave -- 764
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl -- SessionImpl.java -- save -- 756
com.stserp.beans.ManagerClass -- ManagerClass.java -- SaveBeansList -- 60
com.stserp.Program -- Program.java -- main -- 73

could not execute statement
```

Please help me with the Code as I cannot understand why am I getting this `"could not execute statement" error.`

I have tried many things, but none of it worked. Some article even suggested to use `@cascade = {cascadeType = SAVE_UPDATE}` but I don't want to link my table to any other table. I am supposed to maintain all the relations in my code only. There must be some way where tables, if not related to any other table, can be saved. Please help.

Comment: Please try implementing Serializable interface for your entity (although this is not imposed by Hibernate). Also rename _BankBranchContactId to id. And enable hibernate_sql logging to see the sql query fired. Also check if the schema "stserptest" is created properly.

Comment: Thanks Manjunath, The advice was useful. Now I am not getting the specified error. Still even Upon using <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> the new Table (bankbranchcontactdetails) was not created. Can you help me on that too??????

Comment: Vishal if you want to create new table then I feel you need to set <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>. Kindly write the solution/fix which you did for "could not execute statement" error below as an answer to your question so that this question doesnot show up as unanswered and also it would benefit several readers (including me :-)) to know about things we need to take care while configuring entities. Thanks

Comment: Manjunath <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property> will be used to only create table. Second entry gets overwitten. Whereas the <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> , creates and Updates the table. Also, Unfortunately I am still new to  Stack Overflow Please guide me how to get the question marked answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try implementing Serializable interface for your entity (although this is not imposed by Hibernate). Also rename _BankBranchContactId to id. And enable hibernate_sql logging to see the sql query fired. Also check if the schema "stserptest" is created properly.